# How to Automate uploading skill in Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I want to automate the uploading of Alexa Skill. How can we automate uploading of the Alexa Skill. I have a website in which there are 2 fields (AppName,Lamba Function Url) and a button. When user clicks on a button than I want to create the skill automatically.

Comment: Have you researched the API, if you did you'd seen that's not possible yet but likely will be soon. Then try something and show us what you tried and where you got stuck. That's how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using aws cli for deploying codeDeploy Alexa Skills, they currently have a sample Alexa Skill that you could modify to meet your needs.